# No audio when encoding PCM to AAC using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm using MediaCodec to convert PCM data to AAC and MediaMuxer to store this aac data into a m4a file. There is no video.

The file gets generated and will even play. But there is no sound. If I import the aac file into Audacity, it shows no data. The length of the audio is even the expected time. I know for a fact that the data is being encoded although I don't know for certain if this data is being encoded correctly.

Encoding the pcm data:

```
audioEncoder.setCallback(object : MediaCodec.Callback() {

    override fun onInputBufferAvailable(mc: MediaCodec, inputBufferId: Int) {
        updateRemoveAudioBufferIndex(inputBufferId)
    }

    override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(mc: MediaCodec, outputBufferId: Int, bufferInfo: MediaCodec.BufferInfo) {
        val outputBuffer = mc.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId)

        if (bufferInfo.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) {
            audioEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false)
            return
        }

        if (bufferInfo.size > 0) {
            outputBuffer?.position(bufferInfo.offset);
            outputBuffer?.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size)

            muxer!!.writeSampleData(audioTrackIndex, outputBuffer!!, bufferInfo)
            audioEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false)
        }

        if (bufferInfo.flags == BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
            cleanupAudioEncoder()
        }

    }

    override fun onError(mc: MediaCodec, ex: MediaCodec.CodecException) {
    }

    override fun onOutputFormatChanged(mc: MediaCodec, mf: MediaFormat) {
        audioTrackIndex = muxer!!.addTrack(audioEncoder.outputFormat)
        startMuxer()
    }
})

val format = MediaFormat()
format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm")
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1)
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 32000)
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 128000)
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC)

audioEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
audioEncoder.start()


fun encodeAudio(pcmData: ByteBuffer) {
    if (audioInputBufferIds.isNotEmpty()) {
        val bufferId = updateRemoveAudioBufferIndex()
        val buffer = audioEncoder.getInputBuffer(bufferId) as ByteBuffer
        buffer.clear()
        buffer.put(pcmData)

        val flags = if (encodingStopped) BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM else 0

        audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(bufferId, 0, pcmData.capacity(), presentationTimeAudio.toLong(), flags)
        presentationTimeAudio += bufferIntervalInMicroseconds
    }
}
```

I've gone through a ton of examples and everything I've done seems to be correct. If I put a breakpoint in the onOutputBufferAvailable function, it is clear that I am receiving encoded data.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you need to rewind the buffer after putting data in it:

```
buffer.put(pcmData)
buffer.rewind()
```

To be honest, I'm very surprised at the number of sample apps I came across that use buffer.put but never call rewind. Why they even work is beyond me. The documentation on rewind states the following:

> Rewinds this buffer. The position is set to zero and the mark is discarded.
> Invoke this method before a sequence of channel-write or get operations, assuming that the limit has already been set appropriately.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind()

MediaCodec expects the buffer to point to position 0 before it starts encoding. Because I didn't call rewind, the put function caused the buffer to be in the last position and as a result, MediaCodec took that to mean that there was no data to encode. Strange that the MediaMuxer though would bother to even write out data when the codec gave it no encoded data.